# Enumerate within a longtable

Tags: enumerate, longtable

I have been looking through a couple questions, but cant seem to find the answer to my question. I am trying to create a two column table that spans several pages consisting of two `enumerate` environments that have somewhere around 20 items each. Even with using `longtable`, I still only get a table that only runs for one page. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a code snipped:

```
    \begin{longtable}{p{0.4\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{FitsFilter} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Filter} \\
    \hline
     \begin{enumerate}
    \item Read in necessary data from the FITS header and files
    \item Define pretrigger range (ilzero) as a function of the sweeplength
    and the hardware trigger channel
    \item Read in sweep (sweep(i))
    \item For iclass=2

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Subtract the y-offset (yinit) and convert to AD units (divide by $\Delta$V
    {[}V/AD unit{]}) 
    \item Shift (shift()) to common trigger channel (hardware trigger channel
    (nchst)) from calculated trigger channel (tfb)

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Window data with cosine window
    \item FFT to f-space
    \item Shift the channel
    \item Inverse FFT to t-domain
    \item Divide resulting time-domain pulse by the size of the sweep length
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Accumulate 400 pulses (scum) = $S_{cum}(t)$
    \end{enumerate}
    \item For iclass=4
    ....
```

On another note, how do I change the width of the table, so that it covers more of the page.

Comment: On a further note, I am using parcolumns right now to achieve basically the same thing I was trying to do. Is there any way to line up the enumerate options with each other? At the moment it just looks very disjointed

Answer (score 1):

You're doing nothing wrong; longtable can split a tabular only between cells: each cell is an indivisible object and cannot be split across pages.

You can cover all of the page by

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep-0.2pt\relax}|
                     p{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep-0.2pt\relax}@{}}
```

Comment: So I would have to create new cells that continue the count of the the previous cell and size them such that it fits on a page?

Comment: @madtowneast: You might consider also the parallel package.

Comment: @egrep: What about parcloumns? Does that work the same way as parallel?

Comment: @egrep: I have tried out parallel and just overlapping next out. Is there any trick for determining the width of the columns because that seems to be the issue.